# FxCop doesn't resolve external references

Tags: visual-studio-2005, fxcop

Perhaps not a fully fledged programming quiestion, but to help drive the quality and enforce some standards throughout the application I am working on I want to use FxCop.

If I try to integrate into into Visual Studio 2005 as an external tool using the command line

/c /f:"$(TargetPath)" /r:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\Rules" /consolexsl:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\Xml\VSConsoleOutput.xsl"

When running the tool it fails to resolve Web.Servies.2.dll in my resource layer.

I also have a business layer that references my ResourceLayer which also fails to resolve (i.e. running FxCop on the Business layer results in a error saying the ResourceLayer.dll cannot be referenced)

If I run FxCop standalone it works no problem.

Has anyone else managed to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this.

by setting the command line to

```
/c /f:"$(TargetPath)" /r:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\Rules" /consolexsl:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\Xml\VSConsoleOutput.xsl" /directory:"C:\svn\projectDir\ExternalDLLs"
```

where C:\svn\projectDir\ExternalDLLs is a collection of all external Dlls required by the application.